# Fetching Email From MeetUp

Tags: meetup

Am looking to fetch attendees of my event in meet up.

I search for the documentation and get the api to get the list of attendees
[Attendees list api](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/:urlname/events/:id/attendance/#list)

But i don't see email address details in that response. I got the detail i mentioned below from member detail api

**Optional fields parameter. If querying by group and the authorized member is an organizer the member's group, this will return false when the member's email address is known to bounce and true otherwise**

I search for other forums and blogs and came to know there is a exception to get the email address which was mentioned in the forums which i linked below.

[Google Discussion link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meetup-api/MvKmHOoFn08)

Am not clear about what it says, is **MeetUp Everywhere** is the only community which get email in response of the above api ?

Please guide me to right directions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** Meetup don't provide attendees emails on the web, mobile or API

**MeetUp Everywhere** was targeting to organizations to give a way to spark local communities across the globe around their brand or identity, but doesn't worked and Meetup discontinued the product.